# Predict() function in R. How to use it for prediciting a dependent variable

Tags: r, linear-regression, missing-data, predict, imputation

I have a question on how to use the function *predict()*.

I have a dataset with n rows and 10 columns. The first column is the dependent variable and the others variables are independent. I have 50% of missing data on the first variable, namely x1, and the others variables are fully observed. I want to predict x1 (the missing part), by using the correspondent cases and the regression coefficients from the following model :

```
lm(new_A[,1]~new_A[,2]+new_A[,3]+new_A[,4]+new_A[,5]+new_A[,6]+new_A[,7]+new_A[,8]+new_A[,9]+new_A[,10]).
```

Here is my code :

```
set.seed(40)
n=10000 # number of observation
m=10 # number of variables
mis=50 # percentage of missing data on the dependent variable

# I randomly assign 50% of missing data on the first variable (the dependent one in my future model)
for (i in 1:m){
  X[,i]=runif(n,0,1)
}
X=data.frame(X)

# I randomly assign 50% of missing data on the first variable (the dependent one in my future model)
aa=runif(n,0,1)
X_MCAR[which(aa<=sort(aa)[mis*(n/100)]),1]=NA


# First, I create 2 datasets. One for the group A (x1,obs, x2|x1,obs, x3|x1,obs, ..., xm|x1,obs) --> new_A
# and one for group B (x1,mis, x2|x1,mis, x3|x1,mis, ..., xm|x1,mis) --> new_B

new_A=data.frame(X_MCAR[is.na(X_MCAR[,1])==FALSE,])

new_B=data.frame(X_MCAR[is.na(X_MCAR[,1])==TRUE,])

# Second, I stock the result of the regression on the group A in reg_A.
reg_A=lm(new_A[,1]~new_A[,2]+new_A[,3]+new_A[,4]+new_A[,5]+new_A[,6]+new_A[,7]+new_A[,8]+new_A[,9]+new_A[,10])

# Third, I predict x1,obs and x1,mis by using the regression coefficient from A.

x1_obs_hat=predict(reg_A, new_A)

x1_mis_hat=predict(reg_A, new_B)
```

They should be different, but actually they are exactly the same. Could anyone help me and say what is going wrong in the code ? Because x1_obs_hat and x1_mis_hat should be different, because I use different observations for the B group..

Thank you :)

Comment: You are missing definitions for `X` and `X_MCAR` so your example is not reproducible. When using a formula in `lm()`, you should use column names and not literal matrix indexing. `predict()` will not work correctly if it can't translate variable names into new data.frames. Try using `reg_A=lm(X1~.)` where X1 is the name of the dependent variable column and `.` stands for "all the other variables in the data.frame."

Comment: Just don't do this... use EM

Comment: Thank you MrFlick. Sorry for X_MCAR, it should be X instead (which is defined..). Now everything works with reg_A=lm(X1~.) :-)